# Symfony serializer doesn't deserialize json datetime

Tags: json, symfony4, json-deserialization, serialization

I'm using serialize in symfony 4.2 to decode a json and save an entity to the database, the problem are the datetime, when i deserialize symfony gives me an error that expects an datetime object and string was given.

I checked all the "use" statements in my control, as well all the config with the property-info to let symfony recognize all the fields of the json and figure out what it is.

link to the git project:

https://github.com/erethilclaw/lair_of_claw

```
/**
* @Route("admin/newPost", name="newPost", methods={"POST"})
*/
public function newPost( Request $request){
    /** @var  Serializer $serializer */
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $post = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 
    Post::class, 'json');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->json($post);
}
```

the Json I'm passing

```
{
"title": "A third blog post!",
"published_at": "2018-07-01 12:00:00",
"content": "Hello there!",
"author": "Piotr Jura",
"slug": "a-third-blog-post"
}
```

with deserialize method should convert the "published_at" to a datetime for save into database, but gives me the error: "Expected argument of type "DateTiemInterface","string" given at property path "published_at".

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

was my json, the field "publishet_at" in the json has to be as in the class and here is like in the database.

```
{
 "title": "A third blog post!",
 "published_at": "2018-07-01 12:00:00",
 "content": "Hello there!",
 "author": "Piotr Jura",
 "slug": "a-third-blog-post"
}
```

changed to solved the problem.

```
{
 "title": "A third blog post!",
 "publishedAt": "2018-07-01 12:00:00",
 "content": "Hello there!",
 "author": "Piotr Jura",
 "slug": "a-third-blog-post"
}
```